# Return HTML from action / model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

is there any way to make a GET request to an Action and Model combination to return HTML , instead of making a GET request to URI??

normally in my code I would do

```
 return View("myView", myModel);
```

I want to return the HTML from that , and be able to read the HTML.

something like :

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

but to pass and Action and Model

Comment: Do you mean generating a url from an action as in `System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action(...)`?

Comment: I mean like myapp.com/myAction/myView?myModel.1=abc&myModel.2=cde

Comment: Isn't `myAction` actually a **Controller** and `myView` actually an **Action** ?

Comment: yea- whatever, my problem was serializing the model into a querystring , I am just manually doing it now , unless you have a better way

Comment: It sounds to me like you want a 302 Redirect...

Answer (score 0):

There is something [available here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/30/Rendering-ASPNET-MVC-Views-to-String), and you can pass the model as parameter. Although still not sure why you would do this... Alternate source [available on github](https://github.com/RickStrahl/WestwindToolkit/blob/master/Westwind.Web.Mvc/Utils/ViewRenderer.cs).

Anyway, if you only want to alter the HTML somehow an alternative is to redirect to the view and then use an action filter where you can do any post-processing you may need.

What this does is render any view to HTML and return that as `String`. 
Although part of a bigger class, the relevant part is below (`Context` is actually `Controller.ControllerContext`):

```
/// <summary>
/// Internal method that handles rendering of either partial or 
/// or full views.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="viewPath">
/// The path to the view to render. Either in same controller, shared by 
/// name or as fully qualified ~/ path including extension
/// </param>
/// <param name="model">Model to render the view with</param>
/// <param name="partial">Determines whether to render a full or partial view</param>
/// <returns>String of the rendered view</returns>
protected string RenderViewToStringInternal(string viewPath, object model,
                                            bool partial = false)
{
    // first find the ViewEngine for this view
    ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = null;
    if (partial)
        viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(Context, viewPath);
    else
        viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(Context, viewPath, null);

    if (viewEngineResult == null)
        throw new FileNotFoundException(Resources.ViewCouldNotBeFound);

    // get the view and attach the model to view data
    var view = viewEngineResult.View;
    Context.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;

    string result = null;

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var ctx = new ViewContext(Context, view,
                                    Context.Controller.ViewData,
                                    Context.Controller.TempData,
                                    sw);
        view.Render(ctx, sw);
        result = sw.ToString();
    }

    return result;
}
```